# Why can IDataReader class implemented in c# instead of c++?

Tags: c#

I read in many articles that Database connection objects like SqlConnecion, DataReader etc uses Classes implemented in C++ and are unmanaged code type which makes them to be handled manually.

So why can't the implementation of these classes be done in c# itself so that they will be managed by CLR or is there any reason we can achieve this using c#?

Comment: Are you sure? It smells like a lie...

Comment: You're asking a loaded question.  What makes you think we *can't* write such things in C#?

Comment: Here it is [SqlConnection](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs)

Comment: "which makes them unmanaged code"... why does that follow? You can write managed code in C++ AFAIK.

Comment: `I read in many articles...` <= can you provide a link to your source(s)? Seems like a reasonable request considering it is the premise for your question.

Comment: So, If SqlConnecion is implemented in c# they there is no need of using using() or close() or dispose() because they should be managed code. What about DataReader it it also written in c#?

Comment: The class itself is written in C# but it is basically a wrapper around some unmanaged code that uses unmanaged resources under the hood.

Comment: @NithinB I think you're confusing "managed code" with "managed resources".

Answer (score 1):

.NET basically wraps (part of) the native Win32 API with .NET classes such as `SqlConnecion` and `DataReader` which makes is easier to use these API:s without having to write unmanaged code yourself. Of course there are still some unmanaged code involved somewhere to be able to for example access the file system. The CLR itself is not implemented in C#.

Comment: So, Why can't unmanaged resources be made managed?

Comment: Because the CLR and the garbage collector don't know anything about unmanaged resources such as open files and network connections. It provides services to managed code only.

Comment: Lets consider if they are using FileStream class and we are closing it in a close method that we will be called using using(){} or close(). What if they close FileStream after using it in the class methods itself instead of creating one close method in it.

Comment: Sorry but you make no sense. What if "they are using a FileStream class? Who are they? And FileStream is a managed .NET class so I don't understand your question. You should probably read up on the very basics on .NET.